# ArcGIS JS-API, add InfoTemplate to an existing Graphic

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

How can I add an `infoTemplate` to an existing `Graphic` instance?

I'm doing this graphic instances without `infoTemplate` for every point that I have:

```
const layerMarkers = new GraphicsLayer({id: layerId});
this.map.addLayer(layerMarkers);
// Some code
const graphic = new Graphic(point, imageSymbol, null, null );
layerMarkers.add(graphic);
```

Then I want to call some API when I click the graphic:

```
layerMarkers.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(this);
    //Here I can see the object, I need to do something here with it
});
```

What I need is to set:

```
infoTemplate.setTitle(result.poi.nombre);
infoTemplate.setContent(this.getTooltip(result.poi));
```

And then I need to update my graph object with the `infoTemplate`

I can't do:

```
const graphic = new Graphic(point, imageSymbol, null, infoTemplate);
```

Or I will overwrite my object.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [setInfoTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#setinfotemplate) method on the graphic layer to set the template after the graphics layer is already instantiated.

If you just want to show the info window when a user clicks on the graphic layer then just use the show method on the maps InfoWindow instance.

```
this.map.infoWindow.show(e.screenPoint,e.getInfoWindowAnchor(e.screenPoint));
```

after you set the content.

You can also use [setFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/popup-amd.html#setfeatures) which will take a deferred (that eventually returns an array of graphics)

There's a bunch of ways to do what you want depending on the order of the user interactions and whether you are getting data for the popup over the network or not.